# Magento 2 create graphql for get homepage content as result

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento2.4.5, magento-graphql

I want to create graphql to get all content in homepage.
How to create graphql if anyone has idea please share.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve your CMS homepage content via graphql? If so, you should be able to execute the `cmsPage` query, passing in the CMS page identified you have defined for your homepage. Devdocs below:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/cms-page.html

Comment: Thanks for ans. I tried this but, I want all html and products, category data from homepage using graphql